# Issue while detecting touch location inside a view controller in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am using the following code to detect touch location inside my view controller, but, when I exit the view controller, it is still detecting my touch outside that particular view controller resulting in-app crash. I would appreciate if anyone could please let me know how shall I fix my touchesbegan function to eliminate this issue? Thanks!

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
  // First touch to start the game
  if gameState == .ready {
    startGame()
  }
  
    if let touchLocation = event?.allTouches?.first?.location(in: self.view) {
    // Move the player to the new position
    movePlayer(to: touchLocation)
    
    // Move all enemies to the new position to trace the player
    moveEnemies(to: touchLocation)
  }

}
```

This is the code which is called after the game is over :-

```
func displayGameOverAlert() {
  let (title, message) = getGameOverTitleAndMessage()
  let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Game Over", message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
  let action = UIAlertAction(title: title, style: .default,
                             handler: { _ in
                              self.prepareGame()
    }
  )
  let action_2 = UIAlertAction(title: "Main Menu", style: .default, handler: { _ in
                                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "2to1segue", sender: self)})
  alert.addAction(action)
  alert.addAction(action_2)
  self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: I feel like some relevant code is missing, such as how you dismiss/close the `ViewController`.

Comment: @JeroenJK I have updated my question with the code that performs segue with another view controller after exiting the game view controller

Comment: Okay, so you're not dismissing the VC but rather displaying an alert over it.
You could for example use `gameState` inside `touchedBegin`. For example `guard gameState == .active else { return }`.

Comment: Did that work as a solution for you? I posted it as an answer for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell what is exactly going wrong, as not all code is present. But one possible solution is the following:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    // First touch to start the game
    if gameState == .ready {
        startGame()
    }

    // Check if the game is currently active. If not, return from the function to avoid moving the player.       
    guard gameState == .active else { return }

    if let touchLocation = event?.allTouches?.first?.location(in: self.view) {
        // Move the player to the new position
        movePlayer(to: touchLocation)
    
        // Move all enemies to the new position to trace the player
        moveEnemies(to: touchLocation)
    }
}
```

The reason why the `touchesBegan` is still being called is because you're presenting an alert over the `viewController`, but not dismissing it.